# How to move files with a particular timestamp in linux?

Tags: files, directory, timestamps, mv

I want to move some files from /usr/local/packageA directory to /usr/local/packageB directory. I accidentally installed both the packages in the same directory and want to move the files which were installed later to the packageB directory.

Comment: It would be easiest to just delete the installation and install the two separate packages again, correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can move using cp -pr /usr/local/packageA  /usr/local/packageB

where,
p  - preservers the permission from /usr/local/packageA to /usr/local/packageB directory
r  - copy all files and directories recursively from source to destn

or

You can tar the source directory (/usr/local/packageA) and untar it under destination directory (/usr/local/packageB)

cd /usr/local/packageB ; tar -cvf /tmp/soruceA.tar * ; cd /usr/local/packageA ; tar -xvf /tmp/sourceA.tar

Hope this will helps.